# Reset Kendo Grid column

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have kendo Grid column like this:

```
$("#lstCategory").kendoGrid({
  dataSource: {
    data: info,
    autoSync: true,
    schema: {
      model: {
        fields: {
          category: { editable: false, type: "string" },
          subCategory: { editable: false, type: "string" }
        }
      }
    },
    pageSize: 7,
    group: {
      field: "category",
      aggregates: [
        { field: "category", aggregate: "count" }
      ]
    }
  },
  sortable: true,
  scrollable: false,
  pageable: true,
  editable: true,
  columns: [
    { field: "category", title: "Categoría", aggregates: ["count"], groupFooterTemplate: "Total: #=count#" },
    { field: "subCategory", title: "Subcategoria" },
    { command: "destroy", title: "", width: "150px" }

  ]
});
}
```

There I add fields for post action. The problem is I want to reset this grid after post to flush it and insert another value I try to use the next commands:

```
$("#lstCategory").empty(); // this one dissapear kendo grid
$('#lstCategory').data('kendoGrid').refresh();
$('#lstCategory').data().kendoGrid.destroy();
```

but none of them flush my kendo after post, what can be the problem there?

Update:

Try as Dread Pirate answer:

after post action I send this:

```
var grid = $("#lstCategory").getKendoGrid();
var info = refeshInfoFromServer();
grid.dataSource.data(info);

function refeshInfoFromServer() {
  return $("#lstCategory").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
}
```

It appears to work, but my page gets stuck in loading. Google Chrome Inspector return

> kendo.all.min.js:11 Uncaught TypeError: e.slice is not a function

Comment: Slice error is thrown when your schema does not match to object which you get from server or from given list of objects. You need to define in what property data comes. If you do not specifiy it works with some default value. http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource

Comment: That's not what I suggested...you need to re-populate info from the server *however you did it the first time*.  There is no way that info = grid.dataSource.read() as the read() method returns a Promise *not* data.  So, what you are doing now is setting the data of the dataSource to a Promise...which isn't even remotely going to work and is why you get the slice error...as the slice is being invoked on the Promise you shoved in there instead of a legitimate array of data.  You need to show us how info was populated in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You want to re-read the data for the grid from the server after post?

grid.refresh() will only rebind the grid to the current dataSource...it does not force the underlying dataSource to re-read from the server. http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#methods-refresh

What you normally want to do to force a grid to hit the server again is to use the underlying dataSource's read() method(http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-read), i.e:

```
$("#lstCategory").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
```

But, this will only hit the server IF the dataSource is bound to a remote read end-point, otherwise it just re-reads the local array...your dataSource's data is coming from the mysterious variable called "info", which is probably an already-fetched array, yes?

In that case, you would need to first force the info array to be refreshed(by doing whatever you did to fill it the first time again) THEN update the grid's dataSource with the new data, THEN rebind the grid.

Something like this:

```
// Do Post or whatever...
var grid = $("#lstCategory").getKendoGrid();
info = refeshInfoFromServer();
grid.dataSource.data(info);
//grid.refresh(); // NOTE: not necessary as .data(info) will automatically do rebind to the grid it belongs to.automatically do this.
```

Working demo with fake data: http://dojo.telerik.com/@Stephen/aGAQo

Comment: I try as your answer but I get an issue, I post it in my question, can you review it please?